# How to consume kafka topic?

Tags: python, apache-kafka

So my colleague just gave me the info about the topics. We have a very small team and I have to figure out how to consume it.

Here is the detail.

`MM_PROXY_STAGE_USERNAME: xyz`

`MM_PROXY_STAGE_PASSWORD: xyz`

`bootstrap-servers: server1,server2,server3`

`Topics: topic1 / topic2`

Here what I tried from looking at the internet

```
import json
import kafka

def consume_data():
    consumer = kafka.KafkaConsumer(
        'topic1', 
        bootstrap_servers = 'localhost:9092',
        client_id = 'server1',
        key_deserializer = lambda k: k.decode('utf-8'),
        value_deserializer = lambda v: json.loads(v.decode('utf-8'))
    )
    
    for message in consumer:
        print(message)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    consume_data()
```

This code just keeps running and nothing happens.

Comment: It's possible your topic is empty, therefore the consumer has nothing to do but wait

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the authentication and credentials configuration step.
To consume data from Kafka, you need to pass the credentials (username and password) to the `KafkaConsumer` object. Adding these to your code:

```
import json
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

def consume_data():
    consumer = KafkaConsumer(
        'topic1',
        bootstrap_servers='server1:9092,server2:9092,server3:9092',
        security_protocol='SASL_PLAINTEXT',
        sasl_mechanism='PLAIN',
        sasl_plain_username='xyz',
        sasl_plain_password='xyz',
        value_deserializer=lambda v: json.loads(v.decode('utf-8'))
    )

    for message in consumer:
        print(message.value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    consume_data()
```

Replace 'server1:9092,server2:9092,server3:9092' with the actual bootstrap servers' provided. Also change 'xyz' to the correct credentials aka (MM_PROXY_STAGE_USERNAME and MM_PROXY_STAGE_PASSWORD)

Comment: I am getting this error. NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable

Comment: This means Kafka is unable to establish a connection to the specified bootstrap server, which could be due to a number of reasons. Check server URLs are correct, network is running, and your creds are valid. Verify that the Kafka cluster is functioning properly and able to accept connections. Also, verify the security protocol and SASL mechanism: Check the SASL used by your Kafka cluster matches the configuration in your code.

Comment: I am little confused. the kafka cluster is running on localhost. How would it connect to something that's on cloud? Do I need another kafka cluster on cloud?

Comment: It can connect to localhost or the cloud. If you want to use localhost for development or testing, the steps are basically the same for network, credentials, cluster config, security protocol etc. Cloud connections would usually be for production or team collaboration, among other needs.

Comment: @slinger If Kafka is running "on localhost", then how is "your team" giving you access to the "same cluster"? In other words, what you just described sounds like you have attempted to connect to a local broker (which is not running, according to your first error), not a shared one